# Assigning static IP to VPN server

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, static-ip

I have a Win2008 R2 server that is going to be receiving many VPN connections. I want to be able to staticly set the IP addresses of both ends of each connection based on the user. I easily found how to do this for the client: when you're managing the user account, go to "Dial-In" and click "Assign Static IP Addresses." Now, whenever a certain account dials in, I have control over their client VIP, but how do I set my server VIP for each account?